# solr response vs qtime

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr6

I have a solr query that has a qtime of 30-40ms. The response time varies around 200ms.

- Fetching 800 documents at a time
- Returning 10 fields from the search query
- solr version 6.6

[Solr Qtime - ~30ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/504Vr.png)

[Solr response time - ~200ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZkU3.png)

[Cache statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkEo2.png)

If you see cache statistics,

- QueryresultCache hits is ~10%
- DocumentCache hits is ~30%
- FilterCache hits is ~82%

Is there any setting which I can change to reduce the **"response time"** in solrconfig.xml or jetty.xml?

Should I increase the cache sizes of documentCache/queryresultcache/filtercache further more?

Solrconfig.xml:

```
<filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
             size="1024"
             initialSize="512"
             autowarmCount="0"/>

<queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                  size="0"
                  initialSize="1024"
                  autowarmCount="512"/>
<documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
               size="1024"
               initialSize="512"
               autowarmCount="0"/>
```

Jetty.xml thread pool configuration:

```
<Set name="ThreadPool">

  <New class="org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
    <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
    <Set name="maxThreads">10000</Set>
    <Set name="lowThreads">20</Set>
  </New>

  <!-- Optional Java 5 bounded threadpool with job queue 
  <New class="org.mortbay.thread.concurrent.ThreadPool">
    <Set name="corePoolSize">50</Set>
    <Set name="maximumPoolSize">50</Set>
  </New>
  -->
</Set>
```

Comment: What does "Solr response time" measure?

Comment: We are using new-relic as a monitoring tool. Solr-response time is the time measured by new-relic(which includes searching/fetching the required fields and transfer back the data to the server).